# Spring, JPA,JSF - null pointer exception on the access to data

Tags: spring, jsf, jpa, primefaces

I write web application with spring, jpa and jsf support. In my xhtml web page is table(primefaces) and button, which refresh database. When I try click the button i get this:

```
gru 23, 2014 10:01:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListenerinit INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allowsoptimal performance in production environments was not found on thejava.library.path: C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLSClient\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCLSDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCLSDK\2.0\bin\x64;D:\maven\bin;. 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Settingproperty 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SJM' did not find amatching property. 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: InitializingProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"] 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: InitializingProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"] 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initializationprocessed in 1193 ms 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Startingservice Catalina 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: StartingServlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No SpringWebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 
22:01:21,254 DEBUG FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl:100 - Registering flow definition'ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/flows/main/main-flow.xml]' under id'main' 
22:01:21,280 DEBUG ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:59 -Adding flow execution listenerorg.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener@16495871with criteria * 
22:01:21,282 DEBUGConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:59 - Adding flow executionlistenerorg.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener@294d6e25with criteria * 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:21 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized INFO:Initializing Mojarra 2.1.10 (-SNAPSHOT 20120625-1354) for context'/SJM' 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:22 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance INFO:JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeansmethods marked with these annotations will have said annotationsprocessed. 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:24 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListenerprocessEvent INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.4 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: InitializingSpring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet' 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: StartingProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"] 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: StartingProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"] 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 13692 ms 
22:01:25,527 DEBUG FlowHandlerMapping:108 - Mapping requestwith URI '/SJM/app/main' to flow with id 'main' 
22:01:25,539 DEBUGFlowExecutorImpl:135 - Launching new execution of flow 'main' withinput null 
22:01:25,539 DEBUG FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl:59 - GettingFlowDefinition with id 'main' 
22:01:25,555 DEBUG DefaultFlowHolder:83- Assembling the flow for the first time 
22:01:25,664 DEBUG FlowExecutionImplFactory:78 - Creating new execution of 'main'
22:01:25,680 DEBUG ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:87 - Loaded[2] of possible 2 listeners for this execution request for flow'main', the listeners to attach are list[org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener@16495871,org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener@294d6e25]
22:01:25,680 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:215 - Starting in org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@6f98bf1with input null 
22:01:25,758 DEBUG ViewState:189 - Entering state'welcome' of flow 'main' 22:01:25,774 DEBUGSessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'name' with value main
22:01:25,774 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'caption' with value null 
22:01:25,774 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'description' with value null 
22:01:25,774 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'flowExecutionSnapshotGroup' with value org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup@67079bb1
22:01:25,774 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:419 - Assigned key e1s1
22:01:25,774 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:67 - Lockingconversation 1 
22:01:25,774 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:121 -Putting flow execution '[FlowExecutionImpl@277b5201 flow = 'main',flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@1144d3e7 flow = 'main', state ='welcome', scope = map['viewScope' -map[[empty]]]]]]' intorepository 
22:01:25,789 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:128 -Adding snapshot to group with id 1 
22:01:25,789 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'scope' with value map['flashScope' -map['messagesMemento' ->map[[null] -list[[empty]]]]] 
22:01:25,789 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:99 - Unlocking conversation 1
22:01:25,789 DEBUG FlowHandlerAdapter:367 - Sending flow executionredirect to '/SJM/app/main?execution=e1s1' 
22:01:25,961 DEBUG FlowHandlerMapping:108 - Mapping request with URI '/SJM/app/main' toflow with id 'main' 
22:01:25,961 DEBUG FlowExecutorImpl:161 - Resumingflow execution with key 'e1s1 22:01:25,961 DEBUGSessionBindingConversationManager:67 - Locking conversation 1
22:01:25,961 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:106 - Getting flowexecution with key 'e1s1' 
22:01:25,961 DEBUG FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl:59 - Getting FlowDefinition with id 'main'
22:01:25,961 DEBUG ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:87 - Loaded[2] of possible 2 listeners for this execution request for flow'main', the listeners to attach arelist[org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener@16495871,org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener@294d6e25]
22:01:25,961 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:249 - Resuming inorg.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@21d18342
22:01:26,519 DEBUG ViewState:289 - Rendering + [JSFView ='/WEB-INF/flows/main/welcome.xhtml'] 
22:01:26,519 DEBUG ViewState:290-   Flash scope = map[[empty]] 
22:01:26,520 DEBUG ViewState:291 -   Messages = [DefaultMessageContext@60573326 sourceMessages = map[[null]-list[[empty]]]] 
22:01:26,631 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:121 - Putting flow execution'[FlowExecutionImpl@3fcc8fc7 flow = 'main', flowSessions =list[[FlowSessionImpl@ef3728a flow = 'main', state = 'welcome', scope= map['viewScope' -map['flowSerializedViewState' -[FlowSerializedView@10e4c9b1 viewId ='/WEB-INF/flows/main/welcome.xhtml']]]]]]' into repository
22:01:26,636 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:128 - Addingsnapshot to group with id 1 
22:01:26,636 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:78 - Putting conversation attribute'scope' with value map['flashScope' -map['messagesMemento' ->map[[empty]]]] 22:01:26,637 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:99- Unlocking conversation 1 
22:01:28,327 DEBUG FlowHandlerMapping:108 - Mapping request with URI '/SJM/app/main' to flow with id 'main'
22:01:28,327 DEBUG FlowExecutorImpl:161 - Resuming flow execution withkey 'e1s1 
22:01:28,327 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:67 -Locking conversation 1 
22:01:28,343 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:106 - Getting flow execution with key'e1s1' 
22:01:28,343 DEBUG FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl:59 - GettingFlowDefinition with id 'main' 
22:01:28,345 DEBUG ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:87 - Loaded [2] of possible 2listeners for this execution request for flow 'main', the listeners to attach are list [org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener@16495871,org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener@294d6e25]
22:01:28,345 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:249 - Resuming inorg.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@19f6d704
22:01:28,360 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:590 - Attempting to handle[org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:Exception thrown in state 'welcome' of flow 'main'] with root cause[java.lang.NullPointerException] 
22:01:28,360 DEBUGFlowExecutionImpl:611 - Rethrowing unhandled flow execution exception22:01:28,360 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:99 - Unlockingconversation 1 
gru 23, 2014 10:01:28 PMorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] incontext with path [/SJM] threw exception [Request processing failed;nested exception isorg.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:Exception thrown in state 'welcome' of flow 'main'] with root causejava.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sjm.dao.ModelDao.findByStartTime(ModelDao.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:127)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:120)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:226)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$Wrappingrunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

NawNeHier.java

```
package com.sjm.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="NAW_NE_HIER")
public class NawNeHier implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id 
    private int hierId;
    private int parentHierId;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String display_name;

    public NawNeHier() {
    }

    public int getHierId() {
        return hierId;
    }
    public void setHierId(int hierId) {
        this.hierId = hierId;
    }
    public int getParentHierId() {
        return parentHierId;
    }
    public void setParentHierId(int parentHierId) {
        this.parentHierId = parentHierId;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDisplay_name() {
        return display_name;
    }
    public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
        this.display_name = display_name;
    }
}
```

ModelDao.java

```
package com.sjm.dao;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import com.sjm.model.NawNeHier;
@ManagedBean(name="modelDao")
public class ModelDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private NawNeHier nawNeHier;
    public ModelDao () {}
    public NawNeHier getNawNeHier() {
        return nawNeHier;
    }

    public void setNawNeHier(NawNeHier nawNeHier) {
        this.nawNeHier = nawNeHier;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void findByStartTime() {
          String jpql = "SELECT n FROM NAW_NE_HIER n";
          this.nawNeHier =  entityManager.createQuery(jpql, NawNeHier.class).getSingleResult(); 
     }  
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="myform">
  <p:commandButton value="Count" action="#{modelDao.findByStartTime}"  update="dataTable"/>

  <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="nawNeHier" value="#{modelDao.nawNeHier}">
    <p:column headerText="hierId">
        <h:outputText value="#{nawNeHier.hierId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="parentHierId">
        <h:outputText value="#{nawNeHier.parentHierId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="type">
        <h:outputText value="#{nawNeHier.type}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="name">
        <h:outputText value="#{nawNeHier.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="display_name">
        <h:outputText value="#{nawNeHier.display_name}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>  

</h:form>
```

Comment: Please embed that exception stack-trace in a code-block (removing the block-quote). (copy/paste from the server log. It is hard to format the given exception message suitable to a code-block)

Comment: Your model dao is a JSF managed bean whereas it should be a spring managed bean. Make sure you have your Spring JSF integration setup correctly, that seems to be lacking.